# Vue.js Axios post not returning JSON format. How can i catch that on Controller?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

Working on tag system using Vue.Js and Laravel. My output axios post function is rendering a simple value like in the picture instead of JSON format.

I use to catch value from JSON in **Controller** like that:

```
$exemple->name=$request->name
```

However, it's not working in this case. Any help ? thanks

**EDIT**

here is my axios post.

```
  function Newtag(i){
     axios.post('/addtags', $this.tags[i].text)
        .then(function(response) {
          currentObj.output = response.data;
          if ($this.tags[i].text.toLowerCase() == 
          response.data[0].itemValue.toLowerCase()) {
          $this.filteredItems.push($this.tags[i]);
          }
          })
   .catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
 });
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Show us how you're making your Axios POST.

Comment: Post controller code and axios call

Comment: In your controller method, you need to `return` some value, or the output will be empty. Try to add  `return $exemple`

Comment: Thank you for your interest i eddited post for you. Actually i don't have an empty value, the value is "output", was just an example.

Comment: i found the solutions, thx anyway. i have to write $this.tags[i] instead of $this.tags[i].text